# What is the best way to configure Application Insights Connection string?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have an Asp.net core 6 Web Api application.

I configured Application Insights through Visual Studio adding a service dependency as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net). I also configured local AppSecrets file to store the Connection string locally.

Now I notice that the code which was automatically generated in Program.cs takes a variable as a parameter:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
```

I am wondering - is this parameter really needed?

As I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#user-secrets-and-other-configuration-providers):

> ... calling services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() automatically
> reads the connection string from
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration of the application.
> There's no need to explicitly provide the IConfiguration.

If I remove it in my local environment, it works just fine and still sends logs to App. Insights.

So 2 questions:

1. Why does the autogenerated code include this parameter?
2. If I remove the parameter - will it cause any problems when the app gets deployed on test or production?

Answer (score 2):

So the official documentation is vague on all this and a few sentences would add so much clarity, so let me try and assist.

> Why does the autogenerated code include this parameter?

As of VS2022, when integrating the AppInsights SDK, that `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` is no longer added as a parameter and this will be the line of code:

`builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`

Per that documentation you linked ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#user-secrets-and-other-configuration-providers)) the advice is correct. The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration` automatically will read the connection string if the correct nomenclature is used. For example, if you have already configured AppInsights in Azure, you will see under `Configuration` for the App Service the following value:

`APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING`

That value will be read automatically once deployed to each environment; no additional connection string information needs to be added locally in the main source to `appsettings.json`. It will allow AppInsights to work locally and deployed, so long as those connection strings exist in Azure (which get automatically created for you in Azure when configuring AppInsights, or you can configure using DevOps via ARM templates, etc.)

This GitHub [link](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1882) explains the behavior well of how they read the configuration provider upon calling `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()`

> If I remove the parameter - will it cause any problems when the app
> gets deployed on test or production?

So this is the cool part that's vague - removing that parameter will not cause it to break when deployed, *and* will work for multiple environments as the value read will be picked up with the same key name per different environments. Therefore unless you *explicitly* have a value to override in `appsettings.json` in your own source, you can strictly leave all the connection string values in Azure for 1..n environments, and the single line of `builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` will look for `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` in appsettings.json per each deployed environment.